# How to overload operator==() for a pointer to the class?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

I have a class called `AString`. It is pretty basic:

```
class AString
{
public:
    AString(const char *pSetString = NULL);
    ~AString();
    bool operator==(const AString &pSetString);
    ...

protected:
    char *pData;
    int   iDataSize;
}
```

Now I want to write code like this:

```
AString *myString = new AString("foo");
if (myString == "bar") {
    /* and so on... */
}
```

However, the existing comparison operator only supports

```
if (*myString == "bar")
```

If I omit that asterisk, the compiler is unhappy.

Is there a way to allow the comparison operator to compare `*AString` with `const char*`?

Comment: This question has already been raised before:
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626199/overloading-operator-c-pointer-to-class)

Comment: Why do you dynamically allocate `myString`? Why isn't `operator==` a `const` member? Or better, why is it a member at all? Or even better, why are you writing your own string class?

Comment: (1) I shouldn't. That was an error. (2) could you elaborate on that? (3) Why wouldn't it be a member? (4) Because the target platform is an embedded system that has no native string class.

Comment: 2. If you don't make it const then it wont work for const AString:s, 3. Because it doesn't need to be a member and would result in better encapsulation, 4, what do you mean no "native string class"? you have std::string.

Comment: i don't get (3). are you suggesting `operator==()` to be a friend function? why is that better encapsulation?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a friend function. It should be possible to implement from the public interface of the string class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is not.

To overload `operator==`, you must provide a user-defined type as one of the operands and a pointer (either `AString*` or `const char*`) does not qualify.
And when comparing two pointers, the compiler has a very adequate built-in `operator==`, so it will not consider converting one of the arguments to a class type.

Answer (score 12):

Not unless you wrap it in some sort of smart-pointer class, but that would make the semantics weird.  What's wrong with `if (*myString == "bar")`?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is wrong since it obscures the type system of C++. `myString` *is* a *pointer* to a `AString` and not a `AString`. Dont't try to hide the fact that it's a pointer. It's an entry point for ugly bugs and if you're coding in a team everyone else would be nothing but confused!

Answer (score 3):

[ Original answer was wrong and thus corrected below ]

As pointed out by Oli Charlesworth, in a comment below, this is impossible.

You would need to define an operator like

```
   bool operator==(const AString *as, const char *cs); // Note: C++ will not do that
```

but you cannot overload an operator unless one of its parameters is non-primitive type - and pointers (both pointers to AString and pointers to char) are primitive types.

Comment: But doing this could lead to further surprises when comparing pointers afterwards!

Comment: You can't overload operators unless one of them is a non-primitive type.

Comment: ... that should say "non-member operators".

Comment: Well, member operators have an implicit parameter `this` to a non-primitive type, so I would say this holds for all operators.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (myString == "bar")
```

even if you get it to work, is very confusing for others. You are comparing a pointer to an object with a string literal. A much clearer way to get this working is dereference the pointer, and provide an overload like

```
bool operator==(const char* pSetString);
```