# Operator Overloading for struct pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, operator-overloading

I'm trying to compare two dynamically allocated struct pointers using operator overloading. It is to my understanding that operator overloads are supposed to be using pass by reference, so does that mean overloading the == operator to accomplish this particular goal isn't possible?

The goal is to print out Success without editing the code in main()

```
#include <iostream>


struct VAR
{
    int x;

VAR()
{
    x = 0;
}

VAR(int val)
{
    x = val;
}

bool operator==(VAR &lhs)
{
    std::cout << "operator called\n";
    return (x == lhs.x);
}

bool operator==(VAR *lhs)
{
    std::cout << "ptr operator called\n";
    return (x == lhs->x);
}
};

int main()
{
    VAR *v1 = new VAR(5);
    VAR *v2 = new VAR(5);

    if (v1 == v2)
        std::cout << "Success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Fail\n";

    delete v1;
    delete v2;

    v1 = nullptr;
    v2 = nullptr;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you need `*v1 == *v2` to compare the content

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without changing the code in main()?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. `v1 == v2` compare the pointers, i.e. do they hold the same address. I don't think that can be changed. And even if it is I think it would be very bad to do it as it would conflict with other programmers expectation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overload operator==() for a pointer to the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871039/how-to-overload-operator-for-a-pointer-to-the-class)

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf That question is asking about a pointer comparing with a non pointer value. I don't believe this is a duplicate as I'm trying to compare two pointers with operator overloading, if someone feels its a duplicate still though I apologize

Comment: @EvanNudd I think it's a dupe because the answers to the other question perfectly apply to yours. It's just a "possible duplicate" though, and I'm wrong often enough.

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf - I think Evan is looking for a "No, that is not possible" answer and an explanation why it isn't possible. I'm pretty sure it isn't possible but I can't give a reference to the standard which proves it to be impossible.

Comment: @StillLearning If it is indeed not possible, than thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @StillLearning Fair enough. Added an answer with the standard quote to adress that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the other answers, here is the part of the C++ standard that explicitly prohibits operator overloading with two pointers (emphasis mine):

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or
>   be a non-member function **that has at least one parameter whose type is
>   a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration.** It is not possible to change the precedence, grouping, or
>   number of operands of operators. The meaning of the operators
>   = , (unary) & , and , (comma), predefined for each type, can be changed for specific class and enumeration types by defining operator
>   functions that implement these operators. Operator functions are
>   inherited in the same manner as other base class functions.

[[over.oper]/6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf#page.325)

That explains why you can't use an overloaded `operator==` without changing the code in your `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code, almost the same as yours but without pointers:

```
VAR v1(5);
VAR v2(5);

if (v1 == v2) { ... }
```

That condition is actually handled by the compiler as

```
if (v1.operator==(v2)) { ... }
```

When you turn `v1` into a pointer, the compiler doesn't automatically dereference the pointer, i.e. it doesn't to

```
v1->operator==(v2)
```

The simple solution is to dereference the pointers yourself:

```
*v1 == *v2
```

Comment: I think this code doesn't compile because you can't overload an operator if neither of the two operands are user-defined types. Is there something I didn't get?

Comment: I understand what you're getting at with your answer, however I can't seem to be able to define this outside of the VAR struct. It tells me a "nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type"

Comment: It seems I'm getting tired and forgetful, because true and true.

Answer (score 1):

The common implementation of == operator would be

```
bool operator==(const VAR & lhs)
```

Even if you allocate a point to VAR object, you can "call" the == operator using * operator.

```
VAR *v1 = new VAR(5);
VAR *v2 = new VAR(5);

if (*v1 == *v2)
    std::cout << "Success\n";
else
    std::cout << "Fail\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `==` compares two pointers. Pointers are primitive types, **regardless of what they point to**, and [you cannot overload operators when all operands are of primitive types](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#intrinsics-and-operator-overloading).

In other words: Your overloaded operators work if the left operand is a `VAR` and not a `VAR*`.

Of course, your code does not make a convincing point for using pointers or dynamic memory allocation anyway. Just remove all of that:

```
int main()
{
    VAR v1(5);
    VAR v2(5);

    if (v1 == v2)
        std::cout << "Success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Fail\n";
}
```

This way, you also don't need the second operator anymore. For the sake of completeness, you could invoke it like this:

```
int main()
{
    VAR v1(5);
    VAR v2(5);

    if (v1 == &v2)
        std::cout << "Success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Fail\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know for this example it doesn't make sense to do it. I'm having this issue with a much larger piece of code. I just simplified the issue into this manner to get at the main point of comparing two pointers using the == operator, instead of doing the *==*

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>


struct VAR
{
    int x;

VAR()
{
    x = 0;
}

VAR(int val)
{
    x = val;
}

bool operator==(VAR &lhs)
{
    std::cout << "operator called\n";
    return (x == lhs.x);
}

bool operator==(VAR *lhs)
{
    std::cout << "ptr operator called\n";
    return (x == lhs->x);
}
};

int main()
{
    VAR *v1 = new VAR(5);
    VAR *v2 = new VAR(5);

   if (v1->operator==(v2))
       std::cout << "Success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Fail\n";

    delete v1;
    delete v2;

    v1 = nullptr;
    v2 = nullptr;


    return 0;
}
```