# How do you override an operator to be used with a class pointer?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have:

```
class A {
    public:
        operator ==(int int_val) { return (m_int_val == int_val); }

    private:
        int m_int_val;
};
```

I can then do:

```
bool my_func(const A &a) { return (a == 42); }
```

Or even:

```
bool my_func(const A *a) { return ((*a) == 42); }
```

So far so good. But suppose I have:

```
std::list<A *> a_list;
```

And I want to do something like:

```
auto it = std::find(a_list.begin(), a_list.end(), 42);
```

Then the compiler complains because you cannot compare pointer to A with an integer.

My question is not how to solve this with `std::find_if` (just to pre-empt you all). My question is can I define an equivalence operator for pointer to A such that the `std::find` operation above works and, if so, how?

I am asking as I seek to understand C++ better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your operator is equivalent to overloading<sup>1,2</sup>:

```
operator==(A const&, int);
```

So you would like to overload this one instead:

```
operator==(A const*, int);
```

...but [you cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871156/2666289) overload an operator unless one of its parameters has a user-defined type — and pointers to any types (e.g., `A const*`) are not user-defined.

The easiest way here would be to use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead of `std::find` and provide a lambda:

```
auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(a_list), std::end(a_list),
                       [](auto const* pa) { return *pa == 42; });
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> You are actually overloading `operator==(A&, int)` because you did not `const`-qualified the method (this should be `bool operator==(int int_val) const { ... }`).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> For such operator, you usually overload the non-member function instead of the member one.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think your sentence "...but you cannot ..." would be better worded as "you cannot overload an operator unless one of its parameters is non-primitive type - and pointers of any sort are primitive types" (taken from the question you linked). It is a little more specific and so a little clearer.

Comment: On sub-note 1, I think I understand what you mean by "const qualify the method", but I am not sure of the syntax. I rather thought I had written it so it would work with const instances. It would be nice if you could put the syntax you are referring to in the sub-note to help explain.

Comment: @AlastairG I have added the syntax for `const`-qualified methods. I have slightly change the wording of 1, but I prefer to use the *user-defined* version since it is the one the standard use (I am not sure the standard defines *primitive* types).